# Is it possible to enable NNBD for your /lib code, while using legacy packages?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to enable NNBD for my own views and business logic, without concerning myself with upgrading external packages. Is this possible?

Reading the docs here, it sure seems like this is possible: https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

> Mixed-version programs run with unsound null safety. It’s possible for null
> reference errors to occur at runtime, but only because a null or nullable
> type escaped from some null-unsafe library and got into null-safe code.

But the compiler seems to disagree.

I have a pubspec like:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  statsfl:
```

`statsfl` is a legacy lib. I want to use NNBD in my main view, without worrying about `statsfl` internals.

[EDIT] When I try and just let the legacy package be handled by the 2.12 compiler, it will not build:
*"Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety: - package:statsfl"* [/EDIT]

According to docs, I should use **unsound null safety** for this, which is enabled with //@dart=2.9 placed in your entry point.

So I have something like this:

```
//@dart=2.9
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:statsfl/statsfl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    builder: (_, __) => _MyPage(),
  ));
}

class _MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  __MyPageState createState() => __MyPageState();
}

class __MyPageState extends State<_MyPage> {
  int i;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatsFl(child: Container(color: Colors.orange));
  }
}
```

But this is not mixed mode, the compiler does not allow my code to use **unsound null safety**, it just disables it completely. The compiler throws no error about `i`, and doesn't understand `?` syntax.

What I want to do is apply //@dart=2.9 to all dependencies, not the other way around.

Comment: Doesn't work that way.  You're just telling the compiler that *this file* should be compiled ala 2.9.  Won't apply to imports.

Comment: Ok, but is this possible? It can't be a reality that for a developer to simply use NNBD in their own code, they must track down and make sure every single dep they have is non-legacy?? 

This seems completely backwards to what an application developer would want.

Comment: The library has defined whether it is 2.9 or 2.12 (in its own pubspec.yaml).  Your 2.12 compiler knows to shift to 2.9 mode for the library.  There's nothing further to do.  It's far simpler than you make it out to be.  The only disadvantage is that you'll be moving a lot of null checks to runtime instead of compile time.

Comment: According to docs: "To test or run mixed-version code, you need to disable sound null safety. You can do this in two ways: ...  set the language version in the entrypoint — the file that contains main() function — to 2.9" - 

This seems to indicate that 2.9 should enable "--no-sound-null-safety" but this disables null safety complelely. So how do I turn on "unsound null safety" for my own code?

Comment: When I try to just let the compiler handle it, it won't, I get
"The library 'package:statsfl/statsfl.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library."

And when I run, I get: 
CUSTOMBUILD : error : Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies [C:\...\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]

Comment: "should not" just sounds like a warning.  And the error should be a warning too.  If you can make a small repro case, file a bug, because this is supposed to work!

Comment: Ya it is a warning, but the build then fails. Ok great to know that this _should_ work, phew

Comment: So to follow up, the `--no-sound-null-safety` must be passed to run, in order for this "warning' to be ignored. With that, I can do as you say, and run with legacy libs

Comment: Thanks... will note that for future!

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question, it is not clear in the docs, but
`--no-sound-null-safety` must be used if you want to run with legacy libs while using 2.12.

I was confused by this in the docs because it was a runtime flag, I thought something had to be done at compile time to enable it. I didn't realize the flag was required to allow the nnbd code to actually work at **runtime**.

I ended up filing an issue here;
https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1475

It would be nice if there was some guidance on how to setup VSCode and Android Studio to support this in the GUI.